# Fail to compile the Y86 simulatur

Tags: c, linux

here is the error when i going to make psim.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZiibmg.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `mem_wb_state'; /tmp/ccQX7AGh.o:(.bss+0x120): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZiibmg.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `ex_mem_state'; /tmp/ccQX7AGh.o:(.bss+0x128): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZiibmg.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `id_ex_state'; /tmp/ccQX7AGh.o:(.bss+0x130): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZiibmg.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `if_id_state'; /tmp/ccQX7AGh.o:(.bss+0x138): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZiibmg.o:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `pc_state'; /tmp/ccQX7AGh.o:(.bss+0x140): first defined here
```

This is the makefile which is under the  directory 'pipe'

```
VERSION=full
GUIMODE=-DHAS_GUI
TKLIBS=-L/usr/lib -ltk -ltcl
TKINC=-isystem /usr/include/tcl8.6
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -O2 -DUSE_INTERP_RESULT
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your question and add a link to the simulator, and add the output of your shell that shows your command and the commands called by make to compile and link. Is this the complete Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

In every makefile document, for every code referring `cflags` and `lcflags`,  add this:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -O1 -g -fcommon
LCFLAGS=-O1 -fcommon
```